# Computing the derivative of an inner product

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, derivatives, inner-products

I want to differentiate (1) wrt the vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $w(x)$ is a zero-one diagonal indicator matrix

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} g(x)^T w(x) g(x) &&&& (1)
\end{align}

Since

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} g(x)^T w(x) g(x)= \langle g(x),g(x) \rangle
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \langle g(x),g(x) \rangle = \langle g(x)',g(x) \rangle + \langle g(x),g(x)' \rangle = 2 \langle g(x)',g(x) \rangle = (g(x)')^T w(x)g(x)
\end{align}

but the notes I study from says the outcome is $g(x)'w(x)g(x)$

Why is that?

Comment: They forgot to indicate the transpose?

Comment: yes but not just once. Many times the transpose is dropped which made me question myself. If I am missing something

Comment: Does $w$ also depend on $x$? You should check how $g'$ is defined. Is it the Jacobian or its transpose?